# What's the correct relative path to a local image?

Tags: 7, media, uri

I've created a topbar for my website that's displayed the whole time and added an image to it with

```
<img src="sites/default/files/MYFOLDER/IMAGE.png">
```

It looks great on the homepage, but when I for example visit a node, the image isn't found anymore. I guess this problem is caused by a wrong path, but I don't know how to fix it.

What's the correct relative path?

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't work: If you are looking at node/1, the image path is taken as node/1/sites/default/files/MYFOLDER/IMAGE.png, which is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly it is the issue with your **site root**. If your site is on root not in any subdirectory then you can use it like **/sites/all** with front slash in the begining.

You must use the base url variable '**`$base_url`**' to the source of an image that defines the base path of the site. It will works always wherever the irrespective of the root of the installation

```
<?php global $base_url; ?>     

<img src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/sites/default/files/MYFOLDER/IMAGE.png">
```

Hope it works.

Comment: $base_url should be used rarely.  Use file_create_url instead.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it is NOT:
`<img src="sites/default/files/MYFOLDER/IMAGE.png">`.

It should be:
`<img src="/sites/default/files/MYFOLDER/IMAGE.png">`.

The issue you're having is Relative Path URLs vs Absolute Path Urls, see this [stackoverflow in-depth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2005174/1491507).

By having `/sites/default/files/FOO/bar.png` as the `PATH`, you're informing the browser the file is found from the root of the website within the `/sites/default/files/FOO` folder and is called `bar.png` as an example.

By omitting the leading slash, you are saying the file resides in the folder path `sites/default/files/FOO` *within the current directory*. As you navigate the website, node paths and other URLs are rooted in other base directories.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for my problem, combining the answers from @tenken and @TBI Infotech. Using `<img src="/sites/default/files/MYFOLDER/IMAGE.png">` didn't work, because the system was trying to retrieve the image from `localhost/sites/default/files/MYFOLDER/IMAGE.png` - obviously an non-existing directory.

Finally, `<img src="/MYSITE/sites/default/files/MYFOLDER/IMAGE.png">` did the trick.

Comment: TBI Infotech's answer is a better solution. Your solution will require you to change that information presuming you move the site to a production server because it will still be looking on localhost. Using $base_url will do that work for you so long as you configure the site correctly.

Comment: @Geoff: I didn't know that. Thanks for your warning.